# UIButton: superimpose a title on top of an image programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

How do I superimpose a button title on top of a button image programmatically and position them both to be dead center in the button frame overlapping each other?

```
let button = UIButton()

button.setImage(coolpic, for .normal)
button.contentMode = .center
button.setTitle("tap me", for: .normal)

// a bunch of constraints and styling that define the frame
```

Do I have to set the image as a background image? Do I need to create a UILabel as the button title and add it as a subview of the button?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm assuming (I've never tried this) that you've gone through the effort of using a canned `UIButton` with offsets, etc. (If not, why?) So it seems to me that a simple subclass should work. Have you considered this

Comment: Use this button.titleLabel.textAlignment = .Center and add background image to uibutton

Comment: I should have prefaced it by saying that I'm new to Swift. But these suggestions are exactly the things I was looking for.

Comment: @AdityaSrivastava unfortunately that does not superimpose them, keeps them adjacent.

Comment: @thismeanswar can u add some image what you exactly want to display

Comment: @AdityaSrivastava picture a button (200 x 100) with an image in the dead center (center-x & center-y) that is 50 x 50. I want to add a label inside that button that is also dead center (center-x & center-y) so that the image and the label are superimposed.

Comment: Ok nice. Just do all custom. Uibutton 200*100 then add 50*50 imageview on it. Then add uilabel on imageview.

Comment: Does that disable the native button state styling for .normal and .highlighted, etc.?

Comment: @thismeanswar Native button means sizeof 200*100 ? If yes I don't think it will disable styling

Comment: I think you need subclass the UIButton to achieve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with image insets, but I like to use extensions for things like this - that way I can use them anywhere in my app without subclassing. Here's my code for setting an image position in a UIButton:

```
extension UIButton {

    func setImagePosition(at pos:ButtonImagePosition, withAdjustment adj:CGFloat?) {

        let _adj:CGFloat = (adj != nil) ? adj! : 0
        let width = frame.size.width
        var imgWidth = self.imageView?.frame.size.width 

        switch pos {
        case .center: 
            self.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
        case .right: 
            imgWidth = imgWidth! - _adj
            self.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: width - imgWidth!, bottom: 0, right: 0)
        case .left: 
            self.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: width + imgWidth!)
        }
    }
}

enum ButtonImagePosition {
    case left
    case right
    case center
}
```

Then I call it as follows

```
button.setImagePosition(at: .right, withAdjustment: nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
    let button = UIButton()
    button.setImage(UIImage(named:"yourImage.png")?, for: .normal)

    button.setTitle("MyTitle", for: .normal)
    button.titleLabel?.font = button.titleLabel?.font.withSize(15)
    button.titleLabel?.textAlignment = .center
```